# Incorrect MIME type for assets with Valet

Tags: php, css, javascript, server, nginx

Using WordPress and Valet I am getting the following with CSS:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html
```

Response Headers for CSS files:

```
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Wed, 27 Dec 2017 21:59:14 GMT
Server:nginx/1.12.2
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:PHP/7.1.12
```

Response Headers for JS files:

```
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Wed, 27 Dec 2017 21:59:14 GMT
Server:nginx/1.12.2
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:PHP/7.1.12
```

Plugins have been disabled, theme has been switched back to TwentySixteen.

Not seeing this issue on other setups (Homestead) or with non-WordPress sites.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've not been able to find out much elsewhere.

Comment: This is not related to WordPress at all, it doesn't even "see" the headers of those files. You have to set up the content types on the server.